# Can I deploy a .EAR in Glassfish via Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, glassfish

I develop using "Glassfish bundle for Eclipse", that have the internal server to test and debug JAvaEE applications on dev machine. You chan add as many servers you like, but not a remote server. Solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't do remote servers yet via Eclipse.

As a workaround, please export (export menu on the eclipse project) as a war or ear depending on the project type, and get the archive from there.
Then, you can go to the bin/ dir of glassfish and use the asadmin command:
./asadmin deploy archivename

From a local glassfish server bin/ dir, you can also deploy to remote servers via:
./asadmin --host REMOTEHOSTNAME --port REMOTEPORT deploy ARCHIVENAME

See http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-7701/asadmin-1m?l=en&n=1&a=view

Answer (score 1):

Yes, http://glassfishplugins.java.net/  That looks like the complete guide,  it links to [this](http://glassfishplugins.java.net/eclipse34/index.html) page that has really good examples.

Comment: I already have this software, but it don't let you define or manage remote servers. Or I don't know how...